# Save a Json file from an url in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a JSON from the internet which I use in my app. However to make my app more efficient, I want to save this file and refresh it. The issue is that I don't know how to save a JSON from the internet.

I just know these two methods but for a local Json :

```
-(void)saveJsonWithData:(NSData *)data{
     NSString *jsonPath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSUserDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/data.json"];
     [data writeToFile:jsonPath atomically:YES];
}

-(NSData *)getSavedJsonData{
    NSString *jsonPath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSUserDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/data.json"];
    return [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath]
}
```

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: What did google turn up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on the question - your methods above look fine for saving and loading a local JSON file.  Where is the problem?